# globally import stylus file with webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

I've started a new project with vue2 with "vue init webpack my-project"I'm using stylus for styling. So far so good, it compiles everything.

But now I want to have a separate file variables.styl that should be global.

That means I do not want to use "@import('variables.styl')" in every .styl file I have in my app. I've been searching for 2 hours and couldn't find anything good.

For the sake of this post's length, I will not copy-paste the contents of the webpack files here. But will provide you with this link: [click](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SzX70iTp43NTRRQ0w5aklzSTQ)
It's the "build" directory in my project that contains the webpack files

The command is "node build/dev-server.js"

Answer (score 3):

**this is for vue apps created with vue-cli < 3**

According to [stylus-loader](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader), you can achieve this by passing you `variables.styl` file path to the stylus-loader through the `import` option, I suggest you create new folder `styles` inside the `src` directory to contain all your global stylus files (variables, mixins, ...), then pass this directory path to the import option.

- in `build/util.js` before block starting with

  ```
  return {
      css: generateLoaders(),
      ...
  ```

  define variable `var stylesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles')` this will save lot of hassle later.
- now look for line that says `stylus: generateLoaders('stylus')` and pass this `{import: [stylesDir+'/*.styl']}` as second argument to the `generateLoaders` function.

  it should look like `stylus: generateLoaders('stylus', {import: [stylesDir+'/*.styl']})`